# Apache nifi custom Kafka consumer processor produces unexpected record value

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-nifi, kafka-consumer-api

I have written a custom kafka consumer processor for Apache nifi. It doesn't use consumer pool or lease, so it is a simple consumer that processes upcoming records and produces json flowfile based on the value.
Becuase of some problems I am trying to do the same but this time with modifying the Kafka record consumer processor bundled by nifi. Strangely the record.value() is a different bytestream.
This is the onTrigger method of my simple consumer that produces correct record.value():

```java
@Override
    public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {

        final GenericData genericData = GenericData.get();
        consumer = createKafkaConsumer(context);
        try {
            final ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> records = consumer.poll(1000);
            records.forEach(record -> {
                FlowFile flowFile = session.create();
                if (flowFile == null) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    byte[] outputBytes = (record == null) ? EMPTY_JSON_OBJECT : genericData.toString(record.value()).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, rawOut -> {
                        rawOut.write(outputBytes);
                        consumer.commitSync();
                    });
                } catch (ProcessException pe) {
                    getLogger().error("Failed to deserialize {}", new Object[]{flowFile, pe});
                    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE);
                    return;
                }
                flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "topic", record.topic());
                flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, CoreAttributes.MIME_TYPE.key(), "application/json");
                session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS);
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getLogger().error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
```

This snippet of code shows writeData method of ConsumerLease class as part of my modified version of kafka record consumer. This time calling `genericData.toString(record.value())` just gives me the hash of the object instead of a valid json text:

```java
private void writeData(final ProcessSession session, ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record, final TopicPartition topicPartition) {
        FlowFile flowFile = session.create();
        final GenericData genericData = GenericData.get();

        if (flowFile == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            final BundleTracker tracker = new BundleTracker(record, topicPartition, keyEncoding);
            tracker.incrementRecordCount(1);

            byte[] outputBytes = (record == null) ? EMPTY_JSON_OBJECT : genericData.toString(record.value()).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            flowFile = session.write(flowFile, rawOut -> {
                rawOut.write(outputBytes);

            });
            flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "topic", record.topic());
            flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, CoreAttributes.MIME_TYPE.key(), "application/json");
            flowFile = session.putAllAttributes(flowFile, getAttributes(record));
            tracker.updateFlowFile(flowFile);
            populateAttributes(tracker);
            session.transfer(tracker.flowFile, REL_SUCCESS);
        } catch (ProcessException pe) {
            System.out.println(pe);
            session.transfer(flowFile, REL_PARSE_FAILURE);
            return;
        }
    }
```

EMPTY_JSON_OBJECT is just a simple empty json:

```java
private static final byte[] EMPTY_JSON_OBJECT = "{}".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Why you dont use the kafka consumer processor ?

Comment: @maximeG You mean instead of Kafka record consumer or why I modified it? If the latter for some reason I never found out the default consumers bundled with nifi always failed in passing my avro messages. So I decided to write it based on my current applications that are working and this way can add better logging between my code.